# How to list all months in specific period of time which doesn't have any order at that month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to know how to list all months in specific period of time which doesn't have any order. If you can help me.

I have Order Table has OrderDate column

I just make this:

```
select distinct month(Order.OrderDate) from Order where year(Order.OrderDate) = 1997
```

the result will show me the months that have order in specific year only

what should i do to complete this query

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a `LEFT JOIN`

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
(
  OrderDate DATE
);

INSERT INTO Orders VALUES
('2018-01-01'),
('2018-03-01'),
('2018-05-15');

DECLARE @MND DATE = (SELECT MIN(OrderDate) FROM Orders);
DECLARE @MXD DATE = (SELECT MAX(OrderDate) FROM Orders);

WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT @MND OrderDate
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(Month, 1, CTE.OrderDate)
  FROM CTE
  WHERE CTE.OrderDate <= DATEADD(Month, -1, @MXD)
)

SELECT MONTH(CTE.OrderDate) [Months]
FROM CTE LEFT JOIN Orders O ON MONTH(CTE.OrderDate) = MONTH(O.OrderDate)
                            AND
                              YEAR(CTE.OrderDate) = YEAR(O.OrderDate)
WHERE O.OrderDate IS NULL;
-- Add extra conditions here to filter the period needed
```

**Returns:**

```
+--------+
| Months |
+--------+
|      2 |
|      4 |
+--------+
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=be5ec3e16d7628f18fd0277185343325)**

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrieve the months in which no orders are placed for that we can use below query

```
 ;WITH months(MonthNumber) AS
 (
    SELECT 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT MonthNumber+1 
    FROM months
    WHERE MonthNumber < 12
 )
 SELECT DATENAME( month , DATEADD( month ,MonthNumber , 0 )  )
 FROM months
 EXCEPT
 SELECT DISTINCT month([Order].OrderDate) 
 FROM [Order] 
 WHERE YEAR([Order].OrderDate) = 1997
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using left join like below

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3ad66dac8e1d8d3fcc5ea7e43875b920)**

```
select * from  
(
  VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)
) AS M(val)
left join t1 on month(OrderDate)=val
and year(orderdate)=1997
where month(OrderDate) is null
```

Comment: From the OP question _"the result will show me the months that have order in specific year only"_ and your answer do the same.

Comment: @Sami the OP asked - "I want to know how to list all months in specific period of time which doesn't have any order." - you can check  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3ad66dac8e1d8d3fcc5ea7e43875b920

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that if we we have a date range, then we may go beyond single year, for example 01-Jul-2017 to 30-Jun-2018 has 2 years, therefore creating a month range may NOT work in this scenario. The possible solution is to have a list of all the months in range along with the year, so that when we search an order, we'll search by the month and year both.

```
-- this is test order table, just to test the output
declare @order table(OrderDate date);
insert into @order(OrderDate) values('2018-01-01')

declare @dateRange table(d datetime not null primary key);

-- date range input parameter
declare @startDate date = '2017-06-01';
declare @endDate date = '2018-06-30';


-- modifying date range so that we go from start
-- of the month to the end of the month in the range
set @startDate = cast(year(@startDate) as varchar(100)) + '-' + cast(month(@startDate) as varchar(100)) + '-1';
set @endDate = dateadd(day, -1, dateadd(month, 1, cast(year(@endDate) as varchar(100)) + '-' + cast(month(@endDate) as varchar(100)) + '-1'));

-- creating dates for every month
declare @d date = @startDate;
while(@d <= @endDate)
begin
    insert into @dateRange(d) values(@d);
    set @d = dateadd(month, 1, @d);
end

-- selecting all the months in the range where
-- order does not exists
select  cast(year(t.d) as varchar(100)) + '-' + DATENAME(month, t.d) as [Month]
from    @dateRange as t
where   not exists(
            select  1 
            from    @order as x 
            where   month(x.OrderDate) = month(t.d) and year(x.OrderDate) = year(t.d)
        )
order by t.d
```

Output: (notice that 2018-January is missing from result because it has an order)

```
Month
------------------
2017-June
2017-July
2017-August
2017-September
2017-October
2017-November
2017-December
2018-February
2018-March
2018-April
2018-May
2018-June
```